# Android: Change style of EditText inside a Listview programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-styles

I have a listview with 1-Checkbox, 1-EditText and 2-TextView. What I want to do is when i click on checkBox then depending on checked state the EditText style should also changed. I have coded in Baseadapter getView() method like below:

What I am doing wrong?

```
    holder.checkBox.setTag(holder.editText);
     if (boolAdpaterArrayList.get(position)) {
                    holder.editText.setTextAppearance(context,
                            R.style.edittextStyleChecked);
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    holder.editText.setTextAppearance(context,
                            R.style.edittextStyleUnchecked);
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                }
       }

holder.checkBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                    EditText editText = (EditText)buttonView.getTag();
                    if(isChecked){
                       editText.setTextAppearance(context,
                                   R.style.edittextStyleChecked);
                   }else{
                      editText.setTextAppearance(context,
                                    R.style.edittextStyleUnchecked);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: did you refresh the listview adapter again after click checkbox item?

Comment: yes i do by notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Why down voting??? its not a duplicate question. I have searched but didn't got the solution.

Comment: @Clairvoyant the code you spitted out to your potential answerers face ugly formatted, lines are chaotic and probably mixed. Wtf, man? And you're asking why people downvoting...

Answer (score 0):

Use a [check box state changed listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html). If you're using the ViewHolder pattern then you can easily extract the viewHolder from the arguments.
It should look something like this

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) buttonView.getTag();
if (isChecked) {
            holder.editText.setTextAppearance(context,
                    R.style.edittextStyleChecked);
        } else {
            holder.totalRoom.setTextAppearance(context,
                    R.style.edittextStyleUnchecked);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Well I just noticed you're using two different holder items for checked and unchecked (editText and totalRoom). Try using editText or totalRoom in both cases.